# Django : Role based Access Control

Tags: django, authorization, rbac

How to implemet role based access control in Django?

Managing different users based on their roles in a project like User, Admin, Manager ,Teacher ,etc., Is there any open source library available?

I have read about [User authentication in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/). Which deals with roles and groups. Can I define access for different type of users.

Comment: you can assign modules of your project to particular user in Django Admin Authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Use Django groups for manage all the roles you need.

After that from Django admin assign the relative permissions

Docs:

> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/
>   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#topic-authorization